Subscript out of Range error when writing an array from a txt file into a spreadsheet
I have a function within an Excel spreadsheet that pulls data from a fixed width txt file and pastes it into a spreadsheet.  The function currently stores each set of data into an array and pastes it in row by row.  However, I am getting go a point where the txt file has 90,000 rows in it and the processing time has increased for the macro.  I was trying to optimize the macro so that instead of going row by row, it stores all the data into an array and pastes it in all at once to reduce the amount of times the macro calls to the worksheet.  Here is the original code:
Function ImportFixedWidth(FileName As String, _
        StartCell As Range, _
        IgnoreBlankLines As Boolean, _
        SkipLinesBeginningWith As String, _
                SkipLinesBeginningWith2 As String, _
        ByVal FieldSpecs As String) As Long

    Dim FINdx As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim FNum As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim RecCount As Long
    Dim FieldInfos() As String
    Dim FInfo() As String
    Dim N As Long
    Dim T As String
    Dim B As Boolean
    Dim InfoParts As Variant
    Dim rowData As Variant

    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
    On Error GoTo EndOfFunction:

    If Dir(FileName, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
        ' file not found
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Len(FieldSpecs) < 3 Then
        ' invalid FieldSpecs
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
        
    If StartCell Is Nothing Then
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
       
    Set r = StartCell(1, 1)
    c = r.Column
    FNum = FreeFile
  
    FieldInfos = Split(FieldSpecs, "|")
    
    Open FileName For Input Access Read As #FNum

    If StrComp(Right(FieldSpecs, 1), "|", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        FieldSpecs = Left(FieldSpecs, Len(FieldSpecs) - 1)
    End If
    
    Do
        ' read the file
        Line Input #FNum, s
        If (SkipLinesBeginningWith <> vbNullString And StrComp(Left(Trim(s), Len(SkipLinesBeginningWith)), SkipLinesBeginningWith, vbTextCompare) And SkipLinesBeginningWith2 <> vbNullString And StrComp(Left(Trim(s), Len(SkipLinesBeginningWith2)), SkipLinesBeginningWith2, vbTextCompare)) Then
            If Len(s) = 0 Then
                If IgnoreBlankLines = False Then
                    Set r = r(2, 1)
                Else
                    ' do nothing
                End If
            Else
              
    
                If FieldSpecs = vbNullString Then
                  
                Else
                
                    If ImportThisLine(s) = True Then
                        FINdx = LBound(FieldInfos)
                        ReDim rowData(1 To UBound(FieldInfos) + 1)
                        c = r.Column
                    
                  Do While FINdx <= UBound(FieldInfos)
                InfoParts = Split(FieldInfos(FINdx), ",")
            rowData(FINdx - LBound(FieldInfos) + 1) = Mid(s, CLng(InfoParts(0)), CLng(InfoParts(1)))
              
        FINdx = FINdx + 1
    Loop
    r.Offset(RecCount, 0).Resize(1, UBound(rowData)).Value = rowData
      

                    End If
                    Set r = r(2, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' no skip first char
        End If
        
    Loop Until EOF(FNum)
    
EndOfFunction:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ImportFixedWidth = RecCount
    Else
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
    End If
    Close #FNum
    
End Function

I tried to update the code to the following to attempt to optimize the performance:
Function ImportFixedWidth(FileName As String, _
                          StartCell As Range, _
                          IgnoreBlankLines As Boolean, _
                          SkipLinesBeginningWith As String, _
                          SkipLinesBeginningWith2 As String, _
                          ByVal FieldSpecs As String) As Long
    Dim FINdx As Long
    Dim c As Long
    Dim r As Range
    Dim FNum As Integer
    Dim s As String
    Dim RecCount As Long
    Dim FieldInfos() As String
    Dim InfoParts As Variant
    Dim rowData As Variant
    Dim allData() As Variant
    Dim numRows As Long
    
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
    On Error GoTo EndOfFunction:
    
    If Dir(FileName, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then
        ' file not found
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Len(FieldSpecs) < 3 Then
        ' invalid FieldSpecs
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If StartCell Is Nothing Then
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    Set r = StartCell(1, 1)
    c = r.Column
    FNum = FreeFile
    
    FieldInfos = Split(FieldSpecs, "|")
    
    Open FileName For Input Access Read As #FNum
    
    If StrComp(Right(FieldSpecs, 1), "|", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        FieldSpecs = Left(FieldSpecs, Len(FieldSpecs) - 1)
    End If
    
    Do
        ' read the file
        Line Input #FNum, s
        If (SkipLinesBeginningWith <> vbNullString And StrComp(Left(Trim(s), Len(SkipLinesBeginningWith)), SkipLinesBeginningWith, vbTextCompare)) And (SkipLinesBeginningWith2 <> vbNullString And StrComp(Left(Trim(s), Len(SkipLinesBeginningWith2)), SkipLinesBeginningWith2, vbTextCompare)) Then
            If Len(s) = 0 Then
                If IgnoreBlankLines = False Then
                    Set r = r(2, 1)
                Else
                    ' do nothing
                End If
            Else
                If FieldSpecs = vbNullString Then
                Else
                    If ImportThisLine(s) = True Then
                        FINdx = LBound(FieldInfos)
                        ReDim rowData(1 To UBound(FieldInfos) + 1)
                        c = r.Column
                        
                        Do While FINdx <= UBound(FieldInfos)
                            InfoParts = Split(FieldInfos(FINdx), ",")
                            rowData(FINdx - LBound(FieldInfos) + 1) = Mid(s, CLng(InfoParts(0)), CLng(InfoParts(1)))
                            FINdx = FINdx + 1
                        Loop
                        RecCount = RecCount + 1
                        ReDim Preserve allData(1 To RecCount)
                        allData(RecCount) = rowData
                    End If
                    Set r = r(2, 1)
                End If
            End If
        Else
            ' no skip first char
        End If
    Loop Until EOF(FNum)
    
    If RecCount > 0 Then
        numRows = UBound(allData, 1)
        StartCell.Resize(numRows, UBound(allData, 2)).Value = allData
    End If
    
EndOfFunction:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ImportFixedWidth = RecCount
    Else
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
    End If
    Close #FNum
End Function

HoweverI am consistently getting a "Subscript out of Range" error on the following line of code:
    If RecCount > 0 Then
        numRows = UBound(allData, 1)
        StartCell.Resize(numRows, UBound(allData, 2)).Value = allData
    End If


I put a watch on the code and the array is populating as expected with the data from the txt file.  I'm sure there's an easy solution, but is there something that I am missing that would solve the "Subscript out of Range" error?  Thank you very much for the help!

This works for me.  Data is accumulated and written out in blocks until all the file has been processed.
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print ImportFixedWidth("C:\Temp\test.txt", [A1], False, "", "", "12,2|1,3|4,4|12,2|")
End Sub


Function ImportFixedWidth(FileName As String, _
                          StartCell As Range, _
                          IgnoreBlankLines As Boolean, _
                          SkipLinesBeginningWith As String, _
                          SkipLinesBeginningWith2 As String, _
                          ByVal FieldSpecs As String) As Long
    
    
    Const BLOCK_SIZE As Long = 5000   'write this many rows to the sheet once accumulated
    Dim FNum As Integer, s As String
    Dim FieldInfos As Variant, InfoParts As Variant
    Dim allData() As Variant, skip As Boolean, totalLines As Long, numFields As Long
    Dim FileContent As String, Lines, i As Long, n As Long, f As Long, el
    
    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlInterrupt
    On Error GoTo EndOfFunction:
    
    If Dir(FileName, vbNormal) = vbNullString Then ' file not found?
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If Len(FieldSpecs) < 3 Then ' invalid FieldSpecs?
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If StartCell Is Nothing Then
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
        Exit Function
    End If
    
    If StrComp(Right(FieldSpecs, 1), "|", vbBinaryCompare) = 0 Then
        FieldSpecs = Left(FieldSpecs, Len(FieldSpecs) - 1)
    End If
    FieldInfos = Split(FieldSpecs, "|")
    numFields = UBound(FieldInfos) + 1
    
    FNum = FreeFile
    Open FileName For Input Access Read As FNum
    
    totalLines = 0
    ReDim allData(1 To BLOCK_SIZE, 1 To numFields)
    n = 0
    Do
        Line Input #FNum, s
    
        If Len(s) = 0 Then
            If Not IgnoreBlankLines Then n = n + 1 'write blank line?
        Else
            skip = False
            For Each el In Array(SkipLinesBeginningWith, SkipLinesBeginningWith2)
                If Len(el) > 0 Then
                    If InStr(1, s, el, vbTextCompare) = 1 Then
                        skip = True
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next el
            If Not skip Then
                n = n + 1
                For f = LBound(FieldInfos) To UBound(FieldInfos)
                    InfoParts = Split(FieldInfos(f), ",")
                    If Len(s) >= CLng(InfoParts(0)) Then
                        allData(n, f + 1) = Mid(s, CLng(InfoParts(0)), CLng(InfoParts(1)))
                    End If
                Next f
            End If  'not skip
        End If      'blank line
        
        'at the limit for the block? If yes then write it out and clear it,
        '  and reset counters etc
        If n = BLOCK_SIZE Then
            totalLines = totalLines + BLOCK_SIZE
            StartCell(1).Resize(BLOCK_SIZE, numFields).Value = allData
            Set StartCell = StartCell.Offset(BLOCK_SIZE)
            ReDim allData(1 To BLOCK_SIZE, 1 To numFields) 'clear array
            n = 0 'reset n
        End If
    Loop Until EOF(FNum)
    
    If n > 0 Then 'write out any remaining lines
        totalLines = totalLines + n
        StartCell(1).Resize(n, numFields).Value = allData
    End If
    
    Close FNum
    
EndOfFunction:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        ImportFixedWidth = totalLines
    Else
        Debug.Print Err.Description
        ImportFixedWidth = -1
    End If
End Function


I'm really sorry to follow-up, but the only thing that's happening as an error is that if I import a very large txt file (About 90,000 rows by 300 columns), the function is causing Excel to run out of memory.  I tried a couple of different things, but it's still running out of memory.  Is there anything I can do if I have a very large txt file to make it work as intended?  Thanks again for your help!

I guess one approach might be to read the file line-by-line after sizing the output array to (eg) 5000 lines.  When the array is full write it to the sheet and increment the next paste position.  Redim the output array to clear it and keep looping through the file.

See edited code above.  Adjust BLOCK_SIZE to suit.


ReDim Preserve allData(1 To RecCount) is a 1-D array. UBound(allData, 2) raises runtime error 9.

StartCell.Resize(numRows) gets the target range ( numRows Rows x 1 Col).

Application.Transpose(allData) transform 1-D array to fit the target range.


Try
    If RecCount > 0 Then
        numRows = UBound(allData, 1)
        StartCell.Resize(numRows).Value = Application.Transpose(allData)
    End If



How to write a 1-D array to a single row or column on a sheet?

Sub Demo()
    Dim data As Variant
    data = Array(1, 2, 3) ' 1-D array
    Range("A1:C1").Value = data
    Range("A2:A4").Value = Application.Transpose(data)
End Sub



Thanks for the help, I appreciate it!  That is definitely on the right track, however what the above suggestion is doing is transposing my data vertically instead of horizontally.  Also, it also is only putting in the first set of data instead of all sets of data.  Is there any way to paste the data in so it is horizontal instead of vertical?

Sure, try StartCell.Resize(,numRows).Value = allData.

Thanks again for the help!  I tried to update it to StartCell.Resize(,numRows).Value = allData however that doesn't paste any values into the spreadsheet.  The interesting thing is that when I updated the code to StartCell.Resize(,numRows).Value = Application.Transpose(allData) it pasted the first value of each array horizontally in the first row across all columns.  Is there a reason why using just "allData" isn't pasting anything but "Application.Transpose(allData)" is pasting the first value from each array into the first row across the columns?

Is StartCell a cell or cells?

StartCell is defined as a single cell ("A5")

I've uploaded a snippet. I hope it's helpful for you to understand how to write array to sheet.

That did help, thank you very much!  However, the array still isn't pasting the data into the spreadsheet, even after I updated StartCell to a range rather than an individual cell.  When I changed StartCell to a range, it did however paste more rows when i did "Application.Transpose(allData)", however.  If I have an array with many rows to paste (90,000), would I need to make sure the range encompasses all those rows?  It seems to slow the spreadsheet down quite a bit if I do that.  Thanks again!

Please clarify the meaning of the range encompasses all those rows ?  Writing an array (90K items) to sheet only takes 0.04 sec in my test. Your may have other performance issues.

Thanks very much for your help, taller, your snippit helped a lot with learning arrays!  Tim's answer below works exactly like I was hoping!

OP - FYI Application.Transpose has a limit (65536) on the number of elements you can pass to it.  Above that, the return value becomes truncated
